# Unable to create chained SSL certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, jira

I'm trying to upgrade the SSL certificate on my Jira server. Currently, it is working absolutely fantastic with correct chained certificates.

I have one root, two intermediates and one domain certificate.

I follow this:

1. Generate new keystore with alias of mydomain
2. import root certificate
3. import inter1 certificate
4. import inter2 certificate
5. import mydomain certificate

I tried importing the certificate other way round too but no success.

The site works with SSL error and doesn't show the chained information of the certificate in any case.